# align labels to boxplot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I have multiple boxplots which I wish to label with the actual values above. However, I can't seem to get them to align. I end up with something like the following where the labels are not aligned.

[image: Boxplot]
I have tried tinkering around with

```
geom_text(aes(label=value), position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-1)
```

but to no avail. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

My script as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(stringr)

barCount <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year, ~Lateral.bar, ~Bar.accreted.to.island, ~Mid.channel.bar,
  1990,          105,                     134,               62,
  2010,          102,                     189,              102
)


df2 <- melt(barCount, id="Year") %>% 
  mutate(
    Year = Year %>% as.factor(),
    variable = variable %>% str_replace_all("\\.", " ")
  )

barPlot <- ggplot(df2, aes(Year,value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=variable),position="dodge",stat="identity") +
  labs(y="Quantity",fill="")+
  scale_fill_manual("Legend",
                    values=c("Lateral bar"="khaki4", "Bar accreted to island"="Khaki2", 
                             "Mid channel bar"="honeydew4"))+
  geom_text(aes(label=value), position=position_dodge(width=0.9),vjust=-1) 


#modifying axis 
barPlot <- barPlot + theme(
  axis.title.x = element_blank(),
  axis.title.y = element_text(size=14),
  axis.text.x = element_text(size=14),
  legend.position="bottom" 

)

barPlot
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheers, changing `fill=variable` from your geom bar to your `ggplot()` call like so (and by adjusting the horizontal with `hjust= .25` :

```
barPlot <- ggplot(df2, aes(Year,value, fill= variable)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity") +
  labs(y="Quantity",fill="")+
  scale_fill_manual("Legend",values=c("Lateral bar"="khaki4","Bar accreted to island"="Khaki2","Mid channel bar"="honeydew4"))+
  geom_text(aes(label=value),position=position_dodge(width=0.9),vjust=-1, hjust= .25)
```

this results:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time out to answer my question :) Could you explain to me why it only if the fill=variable goes into the ggplot? Because I tried having it with either ggplot and geom_bar and it only works for the former.

Comment: @catlovingtaco It works because `geom_text()` now inherits `fill = variable` from `ggplot()`, & recognizes it as a grouping variable for the purpose of dodging its own positions. Similarly, your original code would have worked if you left `fill = variable` in `geom_bar()`, & added `group = variable` in `ggplot()` instead.